# Powershell exiting loop causes infinite recursion

Tags: powershell, for-loop, recursion, zip, infinite-loop

For some reason, the powershell code below gets into an infinite loop, and I can't figure out why.

The code in the lowest `try` block cannot succeed, so I expect `catch` to catch the error, and then for the loop to continue.

It loops on indefinitely however, creating more and more subdirectories.

Why is that?

Tested on powershell v5.0

Try the code in a folder that contains at least one subfolder, itself containing at least one file. You'll see what I mean.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer} | ForEach-Object {

    $path = $_
    set-Location $path

    #get all items, exclude zip files and folders
    $items = Get-ChildItem -Exclude *.zip | Where-Object { -not $_.psIsContainer}

    #verify that there are items in this directory, catch errors
    if ( $items ) {
        $newfld = New-Item -ItemType Directory -name "blabla"

        #move items to newly-created folder
        Move-Item $items -destination $newfld.Fullname 

        #try to do something that is destined to fail   
        try{
            [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($ZipModule)
        }
        catch { 
            Write-Host "No Zip"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's up with the `try{}catch{}` inside the `if` statement? The string `"No items"` will be interpreted as `$true`, defeating the purpose of `Test-Path` altogether

Comment: What do you mean? The first `try{}catch{}` in the statement is to check that the folder does contain items, i.e. that `$items` is not empty.

Comment: You don't need `Test-Path` for that, just check that `$items` contain anything: `if($items){ # do stuff }`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - That's really useful feedback, thanks! It does not at all answer my question, though. Test the code, you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach to check whether `$items` contain any files is way too complicated, and will behave differently than you expect.

You can check whether any files were returned with just:

```
if($items){
    # move/zip/create etc.
}
```

If `Get-ChildItem` returned 0 files, `$items` will be interpreted as `$false`, otherwise `$true`

---

Regarding the infinite loop behavior, it seems that the `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` keeps running asynchronously in the background and picks up the `blabla` folder that you've created in the meantime.

You can force `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` to return before piping to `ForEach-Object` by enclosing the call in `()`:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer}) | ForEach-Object {
    # create/move/zip etc.
}
```

Or, assign all directories (you really only need the `FullName` property) to a variable in a separate statement before the loop:

```
$Directories = Get-ChildItem -Recurse |Where-Object { $_.PsIsContainer } |Select-Object FullName
foreach($Path in $Directories){
    # create/move/zip etc.
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. I've made the changes, but the code still goes on an infinite loop. Try it in a folder that contains at least one other folder, itself containing at least one file. You'll see what I mean.

Comment: Hadn't noticed the outer `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` call, let me see if I can repro.

Comment: Ah OK, fair enough. Yeah the code is designed to zip the contents of all subfolders. However, I noticed that if the zipping fails, then the loop restarts and it loops on endlessly. By the way, thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @Charon yup, can reproduce (and mitigate) in PowerShell 4.0 as well. See update

Comment: I see..... thanks! That's interesting, and your answer has worked so I've accepted it. Do you have a link with information about this?

Comment: I suppose that another way that I could do it is to pass the contents of the first `Get-ChildItem` call to a variable and then loop over that, right?

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's going in an infinite loop is because you're going into a subfolder, check to see if it has files (non-ZIP files), if so, create a new folder called "blabla" and moving the files into that folder.  So what the code is doing is keep moving files in a folder into a subfolder of that folder, and so on.  If the idea is that you want to move the files into a subfolder and then ZIP it up and delete the files, that will stop the infinite recursion.

Everytime you create the subfolder "blabla", you're perpetuating the recursion.

Comment: I understand that, of course. But the question is, why is it behaving like that? I ask it to get subfolders once, at the beginning, I don't understand why it keeps doing that.

Comment: @Charon because `Get-ChildItem` is not required to return before the pipeline continues. It's a language feature with some weird side effects :)